# Replicate value of a column to next few rows in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe where I have one unique column along with multiple columns as belows:

```
   UniqueNumber Values
0   69444108688 500
1   66023511069 100
2   53313124505 200
3   95336385161 300
4   53923124505 400
5   96498947724 250
6   38933995601 430
7   13182151675 595
8   68184277619 792
9   87329074618 800
```

The dataframe size is around 1000 and I am trying to take few random sample and replicate values of every four consecutive values of "UniqueNumber" column  with it's value at every 5th position. My expected output is as following dataframe

```
   UniqueNumber Values
0   69444108688 500
1   69444108688 100
2   69444108688 200
3   69444108688 300
4   69444108688 400
5   96498947724 250
6   96498947724 430
7   96498947724 595
8   96498947724 792
9   96498947724 800
```

I am trying this by following way. It's changing the column datatype into float type. I am looking for any efficient way to achieve this in pandas.

Below is my code

```
df_sample =  df.sample(100)
unique_vals = df_sample['UniqueNumber'].tolist()

for i in range(0,len(unique_vals) - 1, 1):
    if i%5 !=0 :
        unique_vals[i] = np.nan

df_sample['UniqueNumber'] = unique_vals

df_sample['UniqueNumber'].ffill(axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

Comment: please post the expected output based on the example as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If index is default `RangeIndex` you can use integer division by `5` and then using [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['UniqueNumber'] = df.groupby(df.index // 5)['UniqueNumber'].transform('first')
```

Or if some general index values create helper array:

```
df['UniqueNumber'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 5)['UniqueNumber'].transform('first')
print (df)
   UniqueNumber  Values
0   69444108688     500
1   69444108688     100
2   69444108688     200
3   69444108688     300
4   69444108688     400
5   96498947724     250
6   96498947724     430
7   96498947724     595
8   96498947724     792
9   96498947724     800
```

Another idea is convert float values with missing values to [integers](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
m = np.arange(len(df)) % 5 == 0
df['UniqueNumber'] = df['UniqueNumber'].where(m).astype('Int64').ffill().astype('int64')
print (df)
   UniqueNumber  Values
0   69444108688     500
1   69444108688     100
2   69444108688     200
3   69444108688     300
4   69444108688     400
5   96498947724     250
6   96498947724     430
7   96498947724     595
8   96498947724     792
9   96498947724     800
```